# FB LIKE button - liking only show correct thumbnail + desscription after page reload

Tags: facebook, wordpress, facebook-like, facebook-javascript-sdk, meta-tags

I currently have a "standard" FB LIKE button integrated on my site.

My problem consist of the following:

- *NOT WORKING*: When visiting a page the first time and upon clicking
  the FB LIKE button, the image and description isnt taken from the
  meta tags. [Example can be seen here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wiCzG.png)
- *WORKING*: When refreshing the page and then clicking the LIKE button,
  then the meta image + description is showing correctly. (so need to visit the page one time and then refresh) [Example can be seen here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CKAKS.png)

Im naturally looking for the image and description to show the first time I click LIKE.

**Javascript SDK inserted right after  tag:**

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
```

**Inserted FB LIKE button:**

```
<div class="fb-like" data-href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" data-send="true" data-width="450" data-show-faces="true" data-font="tahoma"></div>
```

**Inserted meta tags:**

```
<meta name="description" content="En hjemmelavet bænk som denne, med plads til opbevaring under låget, er både praktisk og hyggelig i en lille Københavner lejlighed. Lichtenstein stof fra e"/>
<meta property='og:locale' content='da_DK'/>
<meta property='og:type' content='article'/>
<meta property='og:title' content='&quot;Neonliving+Lichtenstein&quot; - Miniaturemaison'/>
<meta property='og:url' content='http://domain.com/beta/neonliving-lichtenstein/'/>
<meta property='og:site_name' content='Site name'/>
<meta property='fb:admins' content='665414800'/>
<meta property='og:image' content='http://domain./beta/wp-content/uploads/2013/05/beanken.jpg'/>
```

Any ideas?